# Simplify $F=MNO+Q'P'N'+PRM+Q'OMP'+MR$

Tags: boolean-algebra

How can we simplify $$F=MNO+Q'P'N'+PRM+Q'OMP'+MR$$ using the theorems of boolean algebra, not Karnaugh or anything else?

Well, I can obviously simplify $MR(P+1)=MR$, so the expression becomes $$MNO+Q'P'N'+MR+Q'OMP'$$ But from here, I tried to use De Morgan or to calculate the negative form of $F$, but none of this helps.

Comment: What have you tried? What theorems/rules do you think you might need to apply? Why don't you include what you've managed to do so far.

Comment: Consider incorporating your above comment into your question.  It will help keep others from telling you things you already know.

Comment: Thanks, I did this. Sorry, I'm new to this site...

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
F&=MNO+Q′P′N′+PRM+Q′OMP′+MR\\
&=MNO+Q′P′N′+Q′OMP′+MR(P+1)\\
&=MNO+Q′P′N′+Q′OMP′+MR\\
&=MNO+MR+Q'P'N'+Q'OMP'\\
&=MNO+MR+Q'P'N'+(Q'P'N')'Q'OMP'\\
&=MNO+MR+Q'P'N'+(Q+P+N)Q'OMP'\\
&=MNO+MR+Q'P'N'+NQ'OMP'\\
&=MNO(1+Q'P')+MR+Q'P'N'\\
&=MNO+MR+Q'P'N'
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought about doing this. Thank you very much!